# Использование MongoDb + NodeJs на AWS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, amazon-web-services

С облачными платформами толком не знаком (разве что с Heroku). Есть проект, написанный на MERN. Используется MogoDB. Хочу обеспечить работу этому проекту на облачном сервисе - AWS.

Вопрос таков. Нужно ли будет платить за услуги MongoDb, если я буду использовать AWS. Могут ли данные MongoDb хранится на серверах Amazon?

Comment: у монги есть своё облако с бесплатным тарифом

Comment: Но они не ведь не будут хранить терабайты данных бесплатно)